# How to pass object to Web API as Parameter with HttpGet

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, webapi, http-get

I am working on .NET 6.0 Web API application. I need to pass object which is collection of string list to API with the purpose it will return data. I can do with `HttpPost` but since I am designing this API for the purpose of `Get` Record, what will be the right approach?

```
public class JobRoleDataView
{
    public JobRoleDataView() { }

    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

this object will get more properties soon so it is not just List...

```
[HttpGet("SearchRecord")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchRecord(JobRoleDataView JobRoles)
{
  //remaining code

  return Ok(returnResponse);
}
```

`error`

```
   TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

Comment: I'd say, you want to violate HTTP principles, but the only workaround IMHO would be a cookie store.

Comment: As long as the method isn't going to modify any data in your underlying storage system I don't see a problem with using HTTP GET. I'm working on the assumption that the data you're passing is for some reason required to generate the response but won't actually be used to change any data in your database (or analogous system). Can you clarify why you think this would be a problem?

Comment: I get error TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

Comment: You can do what you want with passing a delimited list as a param to the API and using a custom ModelBinder that parses the input into a list:
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchRecord(
   [ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomDelimitedModelBinder))] List<string> roles)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FromQuery] attribute and pass roles as querystring.

```
 [HttpGet("SearchRecord")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchRecord([FromQuery]JobRoleDataView JobRoles)
{
  //remaining code

  return Ok(returnResponse);
}
}
```

The request url will be seen as below.
https://localhost:7009/WeatherForecast/SearchRecord?Roles=vishal&Roles=michel